# How can I combine sql aggregate functions with distinct more cleanly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, aggregate-functions

I've been running into the following case repeatedly lately, either I need to apply MAX() or SUM() to one column on a table, but I need DISTINCT sets of values for other columns.

For example consider the following table and associated columns representing details of a login to StackOverflow.

SoUserLogins (OpenIdToken, Name, IpAdress, LoginTimeStamp, QuestionsAsked)

I might want a result set containing users and their last login.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  OpenIdToken,
  MAX(LoginTimeStamp)
INTO #tmpLastLogin
FROM SoUserLogins
GROUP BY OpenIdToken
```

But I need distinct values from the other columns.  I'm going to wrap this in a common table expression (CTE) because I'm going to use it later and don't want to have to clean up another temporary table.

```
;WITH tmpLastLogin_CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
  SOL.OpenIdToken, SOL.Name, SOL.IpAdress, SOL.QuestionsAsked
  TTL.LastLogin
FROM SoUserLogins SOL
JOIN #tmpLastLogin TLL ON SOL.OpenIdToken = TLL.OpenIdToken
)
--Extra SQL using tmpLastLogin_CTE goes here
```

You could change the MAX(LoginTimeStamp) to SUM(QuestionsAsked) in the code above with a few extra tweaks to see a similar example.

My question, is there a cleaner or more elegant way to deal with these situations?

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: I suggest removing the DISTINCT keyword from the first query, as it is redundant and confusing - the GROUP BY clause ensures that only distinct values of OpenIdToken will be returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  SOL.OpenIdToken, SOL.Name, SOL.IpAdress, SOL.QuestionsAsked,
  MAX(LoginTimeStamp) OVER (PARTITION BY OpenIdToken) AS LastLogin
FROM SoUserLogins SOL
```

So you will have multiple rows per `OpenIdToken` and the same `LastLogin` value will be repeated for all rows within a group?

Comment: I think this is probably the way I want to go.  I thought it wouldn't work with Partition By on multiple columns i.e. (Partition by OpenIdToken, IpAddress), but I was happily mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under **Oracle Database** you should **consider using Custom** **Oracle Analytical Function**
which let you agreggate your data by row depending on a column.

As I was writing this, Martin did answer.

But some documentation could be found [here](http://lalystar.developpez.com/fonctionsAnalytiques/) (in french)

Comment: I think Thomas is using a version of SQLServer, based on the insert into the temporary table. I understand that the more recent versions of SQLServer do have similar analytical functions.

Comment: I am using SQL Server. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Mark - Yep. If the OP is on a version of SQL Server that supports CTEs (2005+) they will also be on a version that supports these functions.